# Update field if supplied data is not null in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to update my password field **only if** there's a password (not NULL) in input but at the same time, 'username' can update in the table.

This is my current PHP code:

```
UPDATE `my_tbl` 
SET `username`= '".$dataArray['username']."', `password` = IF( IS NULL('".$dataArray['password']."'),  
   `password`, '".$dataArray['password']."') 
WHERE `id` = ".$dataArray['id']
```

Comment: password = coalesce(passwordparam, password)

Comment: `IF` should be `IIF`?

Comment: @RST Please don't assume

Answer (score 1):

Use concatenation to solve this

```
$sql= UPDATE `my_tbl` SET `username`= '".$dataArray['username']."', 
                    `password` = IF( IS NULL('".$dataArray['password']."'),  `password`, '".$dataArray['password']."')
                    WHERE `id` = ".$dataArray['id'];
```

Change this query into

```
 $condition="";
    if($dataArray['password'] != ""){
       $condition=" , `password` = '".$dataArray['password']."'";
    }

     $sql= "UPDATE `my_tbl` SET `username`= '".$dataArray['username'] ."' ".$condition."
                        WHERE `id` = ".$dataArray['id'];
                        echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($dataArray['password'])       
{
$condition=" , `password` = '".$dataArray['password']."'";   }  else 
{    
$condition="";    
}    
$sql= "UPDATE `my_tbl` SET `username`= '".$dataArray['username'] ."' ".$condition."  WHERE `id` = ".$dataArray['id'];
```

Comment: why you repeated the answer?

Comment: sorry, same code but modified some times without comma might gives error before concatenate..

Answer (score 1):

With codeigniter active records :

```
$data['username'] = $dataArray['username'];

if(!empty($dataArray['password'])) {
    $data['password'] = $dataArray['password'];
}

$this->db->where('id', $dataArray['id']);
$this->db->update('my_tbl',$data);
```